# Resources in JavaFX and Ant

Tags: java, javafx, ant

I have a JavaFX project in Eclipse that contains resources (text data) in /src/res/base.dat file. When I build the project with Ant it doesn’t include this  base.dat file automatically. How should I deal with it?

Answer (score 0):

Add a fileset to the jar target. See "multiple filesets" in https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/jar.html

---

My €0.02: Consider Ant as deprecated and move on to Gradle. Gradle provides (like Maven) a default project structure that will automatically include your src/main/resources folder.

Comment: Finally I used Maven. It let me add resources and build project easly.